# When is "see appendices" wrong?

Tags: meaning-in-context, letter-writing

I'm writing a short letter and want to include 'separately' a supporting document, but I'm unsure how I refer to it within the letter.

The letter is short, and I feel the statement "see appendices" is too verbose.

Is there a word I'm looking for, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: 'See attachment'?

Comment: Or "See attached", if you really want it short.

Comment: I guess, when I think of the word "attachment" I think of email, but yes, that's is ok.

Comment: @MrKnotts Email attachments were named after real-mail attachments. Those were *attached* to the real-paper letter with a real-world paperclip or staple.

Comment: "Append," which is formed from "ad pend," used to mean  attach or affix, and it still does in some dictionaries. Merriam Webster: 1
:  attach, affix <appended a diagram to the instructions>

:  to add as a supplement or appendix (as in a book) <notes appended to each chapter> But the Cambridge Dictionary has a different idea: " to add something to the end of a piece of writing:" I don't want to pick a fight with the English; after all it's their language But at least in the US you can append a pearl right square in the middle of a necklace.

Comment: how about, "see enclosed"

Comment: Yes, appendices is incorrect, and attached and enclosed work well. However, you may be going in the wrong direction with your concern that two words are verbose.  You might do better to flesh out why the reader should look at the supporting document: "See the enclosed document 'Actual Title' for details on the financial reasoning."

Answer (score 2):

> I'm writing a short letter and want to include 'separately' a supporting document, but I'm unsure how I refer to it within the letter.

The word is *enclosure(s)*.  For example, "Please see enclosures."  Or you could talk about the *enclosed documentation*.  Definition:

> 2. Something enclosed: a business letter with a supplemental enclosure.

*[(thefreedictionary.com)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enclosure)*

Below your signature, you write "Enc.:" or "Enclosure:" or "Enclosures:" if there's more than one.  The colon is optional.  Then you list them by name.  For the names, use whatever heading you put at the top of the page of each enclosure.  You may indent if you wish when you're listing the enclosures.  Use a new line for each one.